# Select a group of elements and assign a class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

So what I'm trying to do is break a form into different sections, and show/hide using jQuery.
I have something like this:

I can't change this:

```
<div class="form_row"></div>
<div class="form_row"></div>
<div class="form_row"></div>
<div class="form_row"></div>
<div class="form_row"></div>
<div class="form_row"></div>
<div class="form_row"></div>
<div class="form_row"></div>
```

With jQuery I would like to select the first 4 divs and assign a class 'sec_1' to those divs and 'sec_2' to the last four.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
$('form_row').get(0).addClass("sec_1");
$('form_row').get(1).addClass("sec_1");
$('form_row').get(2).addClass("sec_1");
$('form_row').get(3).addClass("sec_1");
$('form_row').get(4).addClass("sec_2");
$('form_row').get(5).addClass("sec_2");
$('form_row').get(6).addClass("sec_2");
$('form_row').get(7).addClass("sec_2");
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!
A.

Comment: class selectors need a period in front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `class` selector is missing the leading `.`.  Also, no need to split it up so much and grab individual elements.

```
var $rows = $('.form_row');
$rows.filter(":lt(4)").addClass("sec_1");
$rows.filter(":gt(3)").addClass("sec_2");
```

or more concisely:

```
$('.form_row').filter(":lt(4)").addClass("sec_1")
    .end().filter(":gt(3)").addClass("sec_2");
```

EDIT: After reading the note in the jquery docs, even better performance:

```
$('.form_row').slice(0,4).addClass("sec_1")
    .end().slice(4).addClass("sec_2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bstQ5/

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each selected element, if the index is equal to or less then 3, add class sec_1, else add class sec_2.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvTb6/)
http://jsfiddle.net/CvTb6/

HTML:

```
<div class="form_row">1</div>
<div class="form_row">2</div>
<div class="form_row">3</div>
<div class="form_row">4</div>
<div class="form_row">5</div>
<div class="form_row">6</div>
<div class="form_row">7</div>
<div class="form_row">8</div>
```

jQuery:

```
// Notice the '.' in front of the 'form_row', this indicates we are looking for a Class.
$('.form_row').each(function(index, value){ // For each .form_row selected
    if(index <= 3) // If index is equal to or less then 3
    {
        $(this).addClass("sec_1"); // Add this class
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("sec_2"); // Else add this class
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.form_row:nth-child(1),.form_row:nth-child(2),.form_row:nth-child(3),.form_row:nth-child(4)').addClass('sec_1');
$('.form_row:nth-child(5),.form_row:nth-child(6),.form_row:nth-child(7),.form_row:nth-child(8)').addClass('sec_2');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) should be `.form_row`, not `form_row`, which would match all `<form_row>` elements.

Now, instead of multiple calls to [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/), you can use the `index` argument provided by [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(".form_row").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass("sec_" + Math.floor(index / 4 + 1));
});
```